# Determine if a number is a prime without using loops and mutations?

Tags: c

How can I determine is a number is a prime without using a loop? I'm a beginner student and so far I've only been taught functional C. All I am allowed to use is the most basic code like + -, if, ==,!,||....Also, no variable mutations are allowed, all variables must be constant.

Here is my code with mutation:

```
bool prime(const int i, int a) {
    if (a > i/2){
        return false;
    }
    if (i%a == 0){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return prime(i, a+1);
    }
}

# int a is a counter its given initial value is always 2
#prime (5,2) --> false
#prime (9,2) --> true
```

However, as the question requires, no mutation is allowed, and only one variable is consumed so it should look like

```
bool prime(const int i) {
    ...
}
```

I'm thinking of a recursive approach but I just can't quite figure it out.
Also efficiency is not a factor to be considered in this problem.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: With only one parameter, no recursion, and no loops, the only method that comes to mind is explicitly checking against each possible prime from 1 to 2^31 - 1.

Comment: Also, if this is actually an assignment that you have for a class, then I'm fairly sure that either you're not expected to solve it, or you've misunderstood the constraints that are to be placed on your code.

Comment: You need to write a wrapper for the real prime check function, for example `bool prime(const int i)` will call `bool primeCheck(i, 2)`

Comment: @BillLynch: Actually you only have to check if it is divisible by each possible prime from 1 to about 2^16 (exactly to `floor(sqrt(2^31-1))`).

Comment: @rodrigo: Well, that's only 4792 numbers to divide against.

Comment: @BillLynch: Yeah, perfectly doable. I would like to see the reaction of the teacher upon a 5000 line function that fits their nonsensical requirements _perfectly_. I would write `return (i%2!=0&&i%3!=0&&i%5!=0&&...);` and blame the compiler if it blows up.

Comment: `sprintf(url, "https://www.isprimenumber.com/prime/%d", i);` then fetch and parse the page :)

Answer (score 2):

With an auxiliary function it should be more or less easy, although terrible innefficient:

```
bool prime(const int i) 
{
    prime_aux(i, i-1);
}

bool prime_aux(const int i, const int d)
{
    if (d == 1) return true;
    if (i % d == 0) return false;
    return prime_aux(i, d - 1);
}
```

There are some easy optimizations out there, but I omitted them because the code is prettier this way. Also some checks to the input parameters may be needed before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

Only way I can think of is:

```
bool prime(const int i) 
{
  assert(i >= 0);
  return char_array_odd_primes_const[i / 8] & (1U << (i % 8)) ? true : false;
}
```

Where `char_array_primes_const` contains 2<sup>31</sup> bits which are set to 1 for prime numbers and 0 for non-prime.

---

More efficient would be:

```
bool prime(const int i) 
{
  assert(i >= 0);
  if(2 == i) return true;
  if(i % 2) return false;
  return char_array_primes_const[i / 16] & (1U << ((i/2) % 8)) ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
check a given number prime or not without loop,Recursion,Auxiliary Function   

import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PrimeNumberwithoutloop {
    static void PrimeNumber(double num)
    {
        double n=num/6;
        if(n<Math.round(n))
        { n=6*(Math.round(n))-1;
            if(n==num)
                System.out.println("Prime");
            else
              System.out.println("Not Prime");
        }
        else
        {    n=6*(Math.round(n))+1;
            if(n==num)
                System.out.println("Prime");
            else
                System.out.println("Not Prime");
        }
    }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter number to check prime or not");
              double num=sc.nextDouble();
       PrimeNumber(num);

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a Java solution.  The question is tagged with C, not Java.

Answer (score 0):

Randomized Algorithms are known to exist for determining whether a no. is prime or not (and ***most probably they use only a single input***(i do not have idead regarding *all* such algorithms), i.e., the number itself that is to be tested for its primality). These algorithms are proven to be accurate in ***maximum*** no. of situations, i.e., the probability with which they can give the correct result is very high(although not 100% like the usual deterministic algorithms that are written). If you want, you can use them.

Refer to the following link for more details:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Probabilistic_tests

Answer (score 0):

This is the best possible way without using loop.

```js
const isPrimeNumber = (num) => {
        if(num % 2 === 0 || num % 3 === 0 || num % 5 === 0 || num % 7 === 0 || (Math.sqrt(num) - Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num))) === 0   ) {
      console.log(`${num} = is not a prime number`)
      }
      else {
      console.log(`${num} = is a prime number`)
      }
    }
    isPrimeNumber(161);
    isPrimeNumber(25689);
    isPrimeNumber(11);
```